# create changeable datasource for UItableview (using viewcontroller)

Tags: swift, uitableview

i am trying to create tableview that can change the data inside it depending on the brand clicked before, for example if i click on the Acura brand the tableview will then change the array into Acura array and when the car model in Acura is clicked it will show the car year. the problem with my code below is that, when the car brand model are clicked it chooses both the CARBRAND and the CARMODEL at the same time and it show the CAR YEAR. it seem the tableview just keep on selecting the row that i clicked

from here

[image]

then it keep click all the way to the car year 
[image]
both car brand and car model already clicked at this point.
[image]

how do i stopped tableview from clicking twice.
    class jobtypeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
        var thetitle = ""

```
    // car make
        var carbrand = ["Acura","Aston_Martin","AUDI","Bentley","BMW","Buick","Cadillac","Chevrolet","Dodge","FIAT","Ford","Genesis","GMC","Honda","Hyundai","Infinit","Jaguar","JEEP","KIA","Landrover","Lexus","Lincoln","Mazda","MercedezBenz","MINI","Mitsubishi","Nissan","Porsche","Scion","Subaru","Suzuki","Toyota","Volkswagen","Volvo"]

        // car model
        var Acura = ["ILX","MDX","NSX","RDX","RLX","RLX Sport Hybrid","TLX"]
        // car year
        var caryear = ["1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017"]

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            switch thetitle {
            case "Acura":
                return Acura.count
            case "brand":
                return carbrand.count
            case "model":
                return Honda.count
            case "year":
                return caryear.count
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            switch thetitle {
            case "Acura":
                cell.textLabel?.text = Acura[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

            case "brand":
                cell.textLabel?.text = carbrand[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

            case "model":
                cell.textLabel?.text = Honda[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

            case "year":
                cell.textLabel?.text = caryear[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

            default:
                cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            }

            return cell
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if thetitle == "automotive"{
                switch carbrand[indexPath.row]{
                case "Acura":
                    print(carbrand[indexPath.row])
                    tableviewz.hidden = true
                    thetitle = "Acura"
                    tableviewz.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableviewz.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
                    tableviewz.reloadData()
                default:
                    print("hello")
                }
            }

            if thetitle == "Acura"{
                switch Acura[indexPath.row]{
                case "ILX":
                    print(Acura[indexPath.row])
                    tableviewz.hidden = true
                    thetitle = "year"
                    tableviewz.reloadData()
                    tableviewz.hidden = false
                default:
                    print("hello")
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, when the first `if` statement is executed, it changes `theTitle` to "Acura".  Then when the next `if` statement is executed, its condition (`thetitle == "Acura"`) is true and the corresponding statements are executed.  To fix it, use `else if` instead of `if` for the second `if` statement: it will then only be executed if the first `if` condition is false.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if thetitle == "automotive"{
        switch carbrand[indexPath.row]{
            case "Acura":
                print(carbrand[indexPath.row])
                tableviewz.hidden = true
                thetitle = "Acura"
                tableviewz.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableviewz.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
                tableviewz.reloadData()
            default:
                print("hello")
        }
    } else if thetitle == "Acura" {
        switch Acura[indexPath.row]{
            case "ILX":
                print(Acura[indexPath.row])
                tableviewz.hidden = true
                thetitle = "year"
                tableviewz.reloadData()
                tableviewz.hidden = false
            default:
                print("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively restructure the two `if`s as a `switch/case` block.

Comment: i copied the code and somehow it return blank after i click acura.

Comment: @Alan Probably because you have `tableviewz.hidden = true`.